# Django: manage.py makemigrations --> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table

Tags: django, django-migrations

What i did:
- deleted the complete db.
- deleted the content of the migrations folder

then i did:
python manage.py makemigrations.

I get the above error message.

I also did:
- Pulled the github repo freshly
- created venv
- activated the venv
- run python manage.py migrate

it looks like as if the migrate command checks the complete sourcefiles for references to the non existing tables. I am out of ideas here.

Error:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: newshows_setting

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/src/new_shows/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    path('', include('newshows.urls')),
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/src/newshows/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/src/newshows/views.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .tables import ShowTable
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/src/newshows/tables.py", line 8, in <module>
    class ShowTable(tables.Table):
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/src/newshows/tables.py", line 12, in ShowTable
    class Meta:
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/src/newshows/tables.py", line 13, in Meta
    settings = Setting.objects.get(id=1)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 411, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1144, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: newshows_setting
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is identified here in your stacktrace:

```
  File "/home/harald/Projects/newshows/src/newshows/tables.py", line 13, in Meta
    settings = Setting.objects.get(id=1)
```

This means that you're running `Setting.objects.get(id=1)` somewhere in your code as the application is compiling. This will occur before the making of actual migrations in the `makemigrations` command. Refactoring your code to do that call lazily is what will fix your problem.

Comment: how do i call that lazily?

Comment: It depends on your code and how `settings` is being used after.

Comment: Typically it's by passing around a reference to a function that when called would provide the `Setting` instance and that function would only get called when the instance is needed. However, I don't know if that will work for you as I don't know the context.

Comment: in the setting class i save all application settings. so this is used all over the app.

Comment: i would need to refactor the whole application to change that ... :(

Comment: I'm guessing you probably need to anyway because if you're setting that reference at the time of compilation, it won't show any changes you make to the database record while the application is running.

Comment: is there no way to just run the migration without evaluating the complete source? And if i have to refactor, what is the best way to store application settings which also needs to be updated from within the application.

Comment: You could set it to an instance that's not saved yet. So something like `settings = Settings(key1=value1_default)`

Answer (score 0):

Problem was, that i tried to access a queryset which wasn't there yet. I refactored the whole code to use environment variables for the settings.